# How to implement .htaccess redirection with variables

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i need to redirect with variables and i have no idea how to start, it would be great if you can support me,  because i'm new to this.

**from:** */wp-content/uploads/[VAR]
**to:** http://www.test.com/main/wp-content/uploads/[VAR]

*/ = everything in front of /wp-content
[VAR] = variable

thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regex for matching:

```
\*
```

And replace it with:

```
http://www.test.com/main
```

I've no idea of how to do this with `.htaccess`, but I think you may know about this ;)